# facebook photo upload via image data

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm using graph api v2.1. AS3-code generates data, calls JS-code via ExternalInterface, JS-code calls FB API

I'm able to upload photo via {image-url}, but getting error when trying to upload photo via {image-data}:

> {message: "(#324) Requires upload file", type: "OAuthException", code:
>   324}

I guess, i'm formatting {image-data} wrong. here is my code:

AS3:

```
var id:int = Math.random()*10000;

var stream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var imageName:String = id.toString() + ".png";
var boundary:String = "I" + id.toString();
stream.writeUTFBytes(
            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary +

            '\r\n\r\n--' + boundary +
            '\r\nContent-Disposition: file; filename="' + imageName + '"' +
            '\r\nContent-Type: image/png' +
            '\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary' +
            '\r\n\r\n');
stream.writeBytes(picture);
stream.writeUTFBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + '--\r\n');

if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternalInterface.call('savePhoto', stream, null, id);
}
```

JS:

```
function savePhoto(bytes, url, requestId)
{
    var data;
    if (bytes != null)
        data = {"source": bytes, "no_story":true}; //getting error
    else
        data = {"url": url, "no_story":true}; //works fine

    FB.api(
        "/me/photos",
        "POST",
        data,
        function (response)
        {
            //handle response
        }
    );
}
```

**UPD:**

Here is how `picture` initialised:

```
[Embed(source="../res/logo_2.png", mimeType="image/png")]
private var testImage:Class;

<...>

var data:Bitmap = new testImage() as Bitmap;
var picture:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(data.bitmapData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try base64?

```
var params: Object = new Object;
var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(75);
var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(bmp.bitmapData);
params.message = message;
params.image = bytes;
params.fileName = "image.jpg";
Facebook.api("/me/photos",null,params,"POST");
```

https://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

Comment: tnx for response. It is requared to use JS SDK for uploadig image. I tryed to encode bitmap to JPG insteed of PNG, and this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to prepare data:

```
        var pngData:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(image.bitmapData);
        var strForStart:String = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"file1.png\"\r\n" + "Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" + "";
        var strForEnd:String = "--" + boundary + "\r\n" + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Upload\"\r\n\r\n" + "Submit Query\r\n" + "--" + boundary + "--";

        var beginBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        beginBA.writeMultiByte(strForStart, "ascii");
        var endBA:ByteArray  = new ByteArray();
        endBA.writeMultiByte(strForEnd, "ascii");

        var resultBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        resultBytes.writeBytes(beginBA, 0, beginBA.length);
        resultBytes.writeBytes(pngData, 0, pngData.length);
        resultBytes.writeBytes(endBA, 0, endBA.length);
```

Comment: Tnx for response. I tryed this code, and it didn't worked. I logged prepared data into brouser console. There is one moment I can't understand: `length: 7217; position: 7217; bytesAvailable: 0`. Why 0? 
I tryed to set `resultBytes.position = 0;`, but still getting same error.

Comment: ... And one more thing: `shareable: false`. but setting it to `true` changes nothig

Comment: I added one more tip to my answer, maybe it will help.

Comment: I saw this, and did the same. Didn't I?